# Bind a function to String.prototype so it's always bound to the string

Tags: javascript

```
String.prototype.contains = function(str) {
    return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
};
```

This snippet does extend `String.prototype`.
It works well with function calls like `'foobar'.contains('foo')`;
But it doesn't work well if it's passed as a function, not invoking it:

```
var str = 'foobar';
['foo', 'bar'].every(str.contains);
TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'indexOf'
```

I know you could do:

```
['foo', 'bar'].every(str.contains.bind(str));
```

or something like:

```
['foo', 'bar'].every(function(item) { return str.contains(item); });
```

But they just make me feel awkward.
In a `Constructor` function I created, although it doesn't work this way:

```
function Foo(myStr) {
    this.myStr = myStr;

    this.contains = function(fragment) {
        return this.myStr.indexOf(fragment) !== -1;
    };
}
var someFoo = new Foo('foobar');
['foo', 'bar'].every(someFoo.contains)
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I could do this to make it work:

```
function Foo(myStr) {
    var self = this; // Line added
    this.myStr = myStr;

    this.contains = function(fragment) {
        return self.myStr.indexOf(fragment) !== -1; // this changed to self
    };
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to extend `String.prototype` so that I don't have to bind `'someString'.contains` to `'someString'` every time I use it as a function without invoking it.

Comment: The way you are *supposed* to do it makes you feel awkward? Tough.

Comment: @Jon Because I could do it like in the Foo class I created. I use FP a lot and I feel I'd make many mistakes in my program if I don't get the `contains` function bound well to the String, since such usage is all over my program...

Comment: No way for String and i doubt doing it for a MyString type would be useful.

Comment: @octref: `str.contains = str.contains.bind(str)`. But I don't think this is nice to do. It feels somewhat wrong. You would have one string that doesn't behave quite like the others, so now *you* have to remember it's special like that.

Comment: @Jon Yea that would do the trick here but it's not what I wished. I was hoping whenever I created a new string 'someString' and use 'someString'.contains it would be bound to 'someString', as this seems natural to me.

Comment: @octref: You can't do that without creating your own string class, which is obviously a bad idea. Prototypal inheritance depends on the fact that any method `string.prototype.foo` is *not* hard-bound to `string.prototype`, otherwise it just wouldn't work. You 'd write `"foo".indexOf("f")` and `indexOf` would operate on `string.prototype` instead of `"foo"`.

Comment: So... was my answer helpful? solves the issue even though people claimed it impossible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "contains", {
    get: function () {
        return (function(str) {
            return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
        }).bind(this);
    }
});
```

It defines a new property with a getter, meaning every time you "get" the function, for example in `['foo', 'bar'].every(str.contains);`, the function defined above would get called and the return value of that function would be returned as `str.contains`, in this case. The function is the same as yours, only we bind `this` in the getter which is the string, which is what we want.

If `Object.defineProperty` isn't defined in your browser (or anyone to use your code), you can use `__defineGetter__` instead.

A complete solution would look like this:

```
addPropertyWithGetter = function(object, property) {

    getter = function () {
        return (function(str) {
            return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
        }).bind(this);
    }

    if (_.isFunction(Object.defineProperty)) {
        return Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
            get: getter,
        });
    } else {
        object.__defineGetter__(property, getter);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

`addPropertyWithGetter(String.prototype, "contains")`

Comment: Have to aplogize to you. I'm so sorry but I somehow didn't see the notification about your answer. This works great--Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for [**Array.prototype.every()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is the `thisArg`(***Value to use as this when executing callback***).

So you could do with:

```
['foo', 'bar'].every(str.contains, str);
```

For fixing your code:

```
function Foo(myStr) {
    this.contains = function(fragment) {
        // myStr is accessible here
        return myStr.indexOf(fragment) !== -1;
    };
}
var someFoo = new Foo('foobar');
['foo', 'bar'].every(someFoo.contains);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'd like to know if there is a way to bind the `contains` function to the string like the way I bound it to my `Foo` class. In other words, thisArg automatically bound to str when I use str.contains.